# In ascending order i need to print Blanks in last and letters or numbers first

Tags: java

**Code**

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add("Amit");
    list1.add("");
    list1.add("Bhaskar");
    list1.add("Chandan");
    list1.add("");
    Collections.sort(list1);
    for (String Dto : list1) {
        System.out.println(Dto);
    }
```

Output:

> ```
> Amit
> Guru
> Pramod
> ```

Desired OutPut:

> ```
> Amit
> Guru
> Pramod
> ```

Comment: Confused??? what you want and what it prints both are same.

Comment: No, Actually in Ascending order it 1st print blanks and later it prind ascending order. but i want 1st ascending order and later blanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
Collections.sort(list1,Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Instead of

```
Collections.sort(list1);
```